# Essential difference between normal irda mode and low-power irda mode?

Tags: stm32, low-power, infrared

guys, I'm learning stm32f401x mcu. All I have is an rm0368 reference manual pdf file. No mcu chip right now. From the manual, I learnt that `PSC` instead of `USART_BRR` is used to generate baud rate in low-power irda mode. I'v also read the irda spec pdf file, but it didn't help (perhaps I just missed important things). So what's the essential difference between normal irda mode and low-power irda mode, from the point of view of usart circuitry? Does the term 'low-power' refer to the entire irda module in a finished product (due to weaker radiation power), or does it refer to the irda block inside the mcu chip (due to shutdown of certain sub-block under this mode) ? Thx.

---- a related question on pulse generation in low-power irda mode -------

In normal irda mode, we use `USART_BRR` to generate baud rate from PCLK. So the pulse width is basically `3 * (Tpclk * DIV_Mantissa)`, `DIV_Mantissa` is a 12-bit long number.

While in low-power irda mode, `PSC[7:0]` is used to generate irda low-power baud rate from PCLK. The manual says "Instead, the width of the pulse is 3 times the low-power baud rate which can be a minimum of 1.42MHz". I assume that in this mode, the pulse width we can obtain is `3 * (Tpclk * PSC)`, where `PSC` is an 8-bit long number.

How can I get a longer pulse with a smaller divisor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IRDA has a Range^2 dropoff in received energy.

- To be "low power", you either transmit over a shorter distance,

OR

- you use longer pulses allowing longer integration time against deterministic and random noise. Longer pulses require a lower data rate.

Now reread that PDF, with these ideas in mind.

Comment: So the term "low-power" is really used in a product system level. The irda functionality inside the chip is almost the same.